# How to visualize these shapes $\#^k(S^2 \times S^2)$?

Tags: geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

How can I visualize (i.e. "draw") these shapes $\#^k(S^2 \times S^2)$ the $k$-fold [connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum) of the product of two spheres.

This was called the connected sum of two projective planes.  Here it looks like $\mathbb{R}P^2$ rather than $\mathbb{C}P^2$.  Here $K$ is the Klein bottle.

[image]

Comment: One way: do the same with $\#^k (S^1\times S^1)=\Sigma_k$ but declare all the $S^1$ generators in the picture are actually $S^2$.  It is not the connected sum of projective planes.

Comment: $\#^k(S^2 \times S^2)$ is a 4-dimensional manifold. But any connected sum of projective planes is a 2-dimensional manifold.  So I am surprised to see that one "was called" the other one.

Comment: You do not visualize 4-manifolds using fundamental polygon diagrams as you are used to in the case of surfaces. The best visualization in this case is just the definition as a connected sum.